# insert to boost unordered map

Tags: c++, boost, boost-unordered

Hi I'm trying to insert a record into a boost::unordered_map

Map is defined as

```
boost::unordered_map<int,Input> input_l1_map;
```

where Input is the class

```
class Input {

        int id;
        std::string name;
        std::string desc;
        std::string short_name;
        std::string signal_presence;
        std::string xpnt;
        }
```

I use a function to insert the record as below

```
void RuntimeData::hash_table(int id,Input input)
{

  this->input_l1_map.insert(id,input);

}
```

I read the boost documentation it says a function `insert()` to insert data to the container, but when I compile it shows error.

Comment: In future, you should tell us what the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you find such `insert` method?

```
  std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(value_type const&);
  std::pair<iterator, bool> insert(value_type&&);
  iterator insert(const_iterator, value_type const&);
  iterator insert(const_iterator, value_type&&);
  template<typename InputIterator> void insert(InputIterator, InputIterator);
```

Where `value_type` is

```
  typedef Key                                    key_type;            
  typedef std::pair<Key const, Mapped>           value_type;
```

from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html)

You should use `this->input_l1_map.insert(std::make_pair(id, input));`

Answer (score 1):

insert takes a value_type, which is defined as:

`typedef std::pair<Key const, Mapped>             value_type;`

```
void RuntimeData::hash_table(int id,Input input)
{

  this->input_l1_map.insert(std::make_pair(id,input));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most natural way, IMO, to write this would be

```
input_l1_map[id] = input;
```

Allthough

```
input_l1_map.insert({ id,input }); // C++11
```

would be ok too.

Alternatively, there'll be a typedef for the pairs stored in the map:

```
typedef boost::unordered_map<int,Input> InputMap;
InputMap input_l1_map;
```

now you can make it explicit:

```
InputMap::value_type item(id, input);
input_l1_map.insert(item);
```

Comment: operator[] and insert() don't do the same thing though. insert will only insert the new value if no value with that key exists. operator[] returns a reference to the existing value (if it exists) or inserts the value (if it does not) and returns a reference to that.