# Map insert is ambiguous

Tags: c++, boost, boost-container

I am trying to use  `boost::container::map`. During inserting data, the error "insert is ambiguous" is shown.

```
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  boost::container::map<std::string, int> map;
  map.insert("Ram",0);
}
```

Comment: please include the error message, it should contain information on the two (or more) overloads that are candidates

Comment: Cannot reproduce: [I get *no match* for the call](https://godbolt.org/z/z1Dpov). What compiler and boost version are you using?

Comment: I get the same error as @uneven_mark, it works if i `std::make_pair(std::string("RAM"), 0));` though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [insert to boost unordered map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833847/insert-to-boost-unordered-map)

Answer (score 3):

Your style of inserting is not correct. I provide the code:

```
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

int main()
{
  boost::container::map<std::string, int> map;
  map.insert(std::pair<const std::string, int>("Ram",1));
  std::cout<< map["Ram"];
  return 0;
}
```